# How to change the logging level for a particular package using java.util.logging.Logger

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

Say I have the following config for the java util logger I am using

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
```

Now I want to restrict all classes that are in the package org.apache.solr.* to only log WARNING or higher levels. How to I do this through configuration only? ( similar to how we use category in log4j)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `org.apache.solr.level=WARNING`